# Find converging subsequences in a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, cauchy-sequences, algorithmic-game-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\{x_n\}_n$ a sequence. I'm looking for an algorithm that takes $x\in X$ as an input and gives a $y\in X$ as an output, with this property: if $\{x_n\}_n$ admits some converging subsequence then $\{y_n\}_n$ is a converging subsequence of $\{x_n\}_n$.

I started naively with this: let $y_0=x_0$, then take $y_1=x_{i_1}$ where $x_{i_1}$ is the first such that $d(x_0,x_{i_1})<2^{-1}$, if this exists, and $y_1=y_0$ otherwise, and so on. But this doesn't work, since a converging subsequence could easly start at some $n>0$ and i will not find it in this way.

Have someone any idea? Is there such an algorithm?

Remark: this problem could be setting in a two player, perfect information game-context: player I enumerate a sequence by playing $x\in X$ at each of its turn and player II has to choose if take or not the $x$ II just played, in order to have, at the end of the game, a subsequence of $\{y_n\}_n$ such that if $\{x_n\}_n$ (the II's run) admits some converging subsequence, then $\{y_n\}_n$ is such a subsequence.

Comment: Do you mean that the input and ouput of your algorithm must belong to $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ ?

Comment: No, to $X$. The algorithm have to decide, on $x_n$ if you  should take $x_n$ or not.  For instance, if $x_n=\{1,2,1/2,3,1/3, 4, 1/4...\}$ it should say you: pick $1$, then $2$ has too big distance from $1$ (greater than 1/2), so, on $2$, return $1$. Then $1/2$ has a good distance, so on $1/2$ return $1/2$, and so on, requiring the distance $\leq 1/2^n$ for the $n$-th new output. Obviously this algorithm is a special case and can't be good on other sequences, like (again in $\mathbb R$) $\{1,1/2,1/4,2, 2+1/2, 2+1/4, 2+1/8, 2+1/16, \dots\}$ (it would return $1/4$ definitely)